# Do I need a transit visa for 8 hour layover in Dubai

Tags: transit, dubai, dxb

I am travelling by emirates from India to Dubai (DXB) and after 8 hour layover  I will be boarding an emirates flight to the USA from DXB airport.

Do I need a transit visa for the layover period in Dubai?